# How to "save as" (i.e. rename downloaded file) in FileZilla?

Tags: filezilla

When downloading files from my FTP server, I often want to rename the transferred file without modifying the file on the server. Is it possible to set filename when downloading?

Comment: Is there any reason you can not do the download with another software?

Comment: @Albin: No, I've used FileZilla since it seems to be the most common and therefore the most supported client. Feel free to recommend other software, I can update my question.

Comment: if it's just for download I usually use the browser using the "save as" feature when you right click on the link. Note, you have to select each file manually, not sure this is what you want. Anyway the string wor the browser address will be ftp://username:paswort@serverdomainname:port

Comment: @Albin: I didn't manage to sign in with Firefox, I'm redirected to the host's frontpage. But I indeed download often download folders which to my knowledge isn't possible in (this) browser.

Comment: No, it's not possible. If you download the folder, do you change each file individually? For login via FF what do you use as prefix http:// or ftp:// ?? It needs to be ftp. You marked the exiting answer as accepted, is the problem solved now?

Comment: @Albin: I forgot the prefix, sorry. No, I don't generally rename each file individually, only folder when not downloading single files. The question has been resolved, any further inquiries would be off-topic.

Comment: ok, would be nice if you could check if the FF solution does what you want with single files. If it does, I will make it into an answer anyway, maybe it helps others.

Comment: @Albin: The filename can be modified in Firefox like with any other download when signed in to an FTP server.

Comment: ok, thanks. how did you solve the problem do you use WinSCP now or do you download the file twice so you can change the name on the second download?

Comment: @Albin: No, I used Firefox for testing if I can change the filename that way. I signed in to my FTP server (`ftp://`), browser to a file and right click > save file as

Comment: no, sorry, I mean how will you download the files in the future if you need to rename them? And do you think it's worth writing the FF solution as a second answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When downloading file that already exists locally, there's *Rename* option on *Target already exists* dialog.
- When downloading file that does not exist yet locally, there's no problem renaming it after download.
- Also, there's *Transfer > Manual Transfer* command. But you have to enter even source name there manually.

Those are all the options you have with FileZilla.

For other options, you would have to switch to another FTP client. For example with *my* [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/), you can modify name of the target file on [transfer options dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_copy).